# How do you iterate over all columns to plot multiple series in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data already in formatted in columns, and I am hoping to make a line graph, where a single x-axis is plotted against many columns. Each column (Y1, Y2, ...Y500) outputs a different line.

How can I iterate over all the columns to create a series for each X1:Yn combination, while keeping the same x-axis?

Currently, I have the following code, but do want want to manually add all 500 columns.

```
plot <- ggplot(data=myData) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color="blue")) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=Y2, color="red"))
```

Comment: You need to pivot your data into long format, then you can easily get all your series with a very simple plot call. Without a motivating example or reproducible data, the best advice you are going to get here is to look at `tidyr::pivot_longer`. If you want more specific advice, we need a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question to make it clearer hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can stack up your Y's into one column (and stack up/repeat x accordingly), and create a second column - a factor - indicating the variable (look into tidyr::pivot_longer). After having that data frame you can do:

```
ggplot = (data=df, aes(x=x, color=factor)) + geom_line()
# Assuming the data frame is called "df", the x column is "x", and the indicator of variable is "factor"
```

Another way (but the first is probably better), is to do a loop:

```
g = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x))

for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    g + geom_line(aes(y=df[,i]))}

plot(g)
```